# How to find number of days for each month from date range in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table data, how do I find the number of days for each month from this:

```
   serial      |      date_from      |      date_from
   001         |      2012-12-20     |       2013-01-25
   002         |      2012-12-20     |       2013-01-25
   003         |      2012-12-20     |       2013-01-25
   001         |      2013-01-26     |       2013-04-26
```

Required result for the first row:

```
   Serial        |    days  |     month 
   001           |    11    |      December, 2012
   001           |    25    |      January, 2012
```

How can I do this in mysql?

Comment: Is this sql server or mysql? They are not the same thing and the answer will be different depending on which DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a utility table called `calendar` that stores all dates that one is likely to encounter (it's a depressingly small table)...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(serial      INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,date_from DATE NOT NULL
,date_to DATE NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(001,'2012-12-20','2013-01-25'),
(002,'2012-12-20','2013-01-25'),
(003,'2012-12-20','2013-01-25'),
(004,'2013-01-26','2013-04-26');


SELECT serial
     , DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%Y%m')
     , COUNT(*) total
  FROM calendar c 
  JOIN my_table x 
    ON c.dt > x.date_from 
   AND c.dt <= date_to 
 GROUP 
    BY serial
     , DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%Y%m');

+--------+------------------------+-------+
| serial | DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%Y%m') | total |
+--------+------------------------+-------+
|      1 | 201212                 |    11 |
|      1 | 201301                 |    25 |
|      2 | 201212                 |    11 |
|      2 | 201301                 |    25 |
|      3 | 201212                 |    11 |
|      3 | 201301                 |    25 |
|      4 | 201301                 |     5 |
|      4 | 201302                 |    28 |
|      4 | 201303                 |    31 |
|      4 | 201304                 |    26 |
+--------+------------------------+-------+
```

...or something like that

Comment: Yes a calendar table to the rescue!!.. This link has an awesome explanation of calendar tables: http://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit tricky, you need another row source to join in. I'll use an inline view as an example, or this could come from a  table ..

```
SELECT  t.service, expr, DATE_FORMAT(m._month,'%Y-%m')
  FROM ( SELECT '2012-12-01' AS _month 
          UNION ALL SELECT '2013-01-01'
          UNION ALL SELECT '2013-02-01'
          UNION ALL SELECT '2013-03-01'
          UNION ALL SELECT '2013-04-01'
       ) m
  JOIN mytable t
    ON ...

 WHERE ...
```

The tricky part is is getting the expressions for the JOIN right (checking for any overlap of the date range with the month), and getting the expression to return the number of days.

Something like this should return the specified result:

```
SELECT d.serial
     , DATEDIFF(LEAST(d.date_to+INTERVAL 1 DAY,m._month+INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
               ,GREATEST(d.date_from,m._month)
       ) AS `days`
     , DATE_FORMAT(m._month,'%M, %Y') AS `month`
   --  , d.date_from
   --  , d.date_to
   --  , m._month
  FROM daterange d
  JOIN ( SELECT '2012-11-01' AS _month 
          UNION ALL SELECT '2012-12-01'
          UNION ALL SELECT '2013-01-01'
          UNION ALL SELECT '2013-02-01'
          UNION ALL SELECT '2013-03-01'
          UNION ALL SELECT '2013-04-01'
          UNION ALL SELECT '2013-05-01'
       ) m
    ON m._month >= DATE_FORMAT(d.date_from,'%Y-%m-01')
   AND m._month <= DATE_FORMAT(d.date_to  ,'%Y-%m-01')
 ORDER BY d.serial, m._month
```

Answer (score 0):

I would calculate the first day of the next month, and then calculate the difference between the two dates.

```
SELECT Serial, 
    DATEDIFF(DATE_FORMAT(date_from + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01'), date_from)-1 AS `days`,
    DATE_FORMAT(date_from, '%M, %Y') AS `month`
FROM your_table_name
```